# access infopath controls when using multi-threading c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, infopath2010

I am trying to modify a control in an InfoPath form from a method in a seperate thread from the rest of the logic, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work? the reason i am using a different thread is because I am trying to echo the graphic from a signature pad as it is being drawn.

```
public void InternalStartup()
{
    readSigThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
    readSigThread.Start();
}
public void Run()
{
     while (!done)
     {
        SigPlus.SetImageXSize(400);
        SigPlus.SetImageYSize(100);
        SigPlus.SetImagePenWidth(11);
        SigPlus.SetJustifyMode(5);
        Image sigImage = SigPlus.GetSigImage();
        String sigBase64 = ImageToBase64(sigImage, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        DeleteNil(imgCanvas);
        imgCanvas.SetValue(sigBase64); // image canvas is the control that I am trying to change.
    }
}
```

In the original thread I have a button click listener to indicate that the drawing is complete. but after the new thread start the listener seems to stop working as well.

Comment: would an AutoResetEvent solve your problem? waits until the thread is done

Comment: what would that do. wait to register the button click? or wait to draw the image?

Comment: I think i dont really understand what you r trying to do. You should modify winforms controls on the main thread. Waiting until an action is done on another thread can be done with autoresetevents.